# How to mix categorical data that requires one-hot encoding with continuous data in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, categorical-data, continuous

I have a mix of categorical inputs and continuous inputs. Categorical inputs are not binary, so one-hot encoding is required. How can you set such a situation up for tensorflow?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Do you want to mix a regression with a categorization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use feature columns. The Tensorflow docs are the best place to start searching for your answer:

> https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns

To create feature columns, call functions from the tf.feature_column module. This document explains nine of the functions in that module. As the following figure shows, all nine functions return either a Categorical-Column or a Dense-Column object, except bucketized_column, which inherits from both classes:

[image]

To combine the result of your categorical variables with the numerical variables you can use a "deep and wide" model combining the two type of features:

> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

```
for each column in dnn_feature_columns + linear_feature_columns:
- if column is a _CategoricalColumn, a feature with key=column.name whose value is a SparseTensor.
- if column is a _WeightedCategoricalColumn, two features: the first with key the id column name, the second with key the weight column name. Both features' value must be a SparseTensor.
- if column is a _DenseColumn, a feature with key=column.name whose value is a Tensor.
```